# Are vampires able to make babies?

Tags: vampire, twilight

In *Breaking Dawn*, it's shown that vampire males can impregnate human females.  Do vampire females still have working reproductive systems?  Are vampire males and females able to produce vampire babies?

Comment: You opened Pandora's box!

Comment: This question and the answers bring up all sort of questions as to what would be possible in a laboratory. Pandora's box indeed.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://bash.org/?5598

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

Stephanie Meyer has commented on this - vampires bodies are unchanging, so a female vampire will never ovulate.  Without ovulation, there can be no pregnancy.  Even if there was a viable egg at the time of the transformation, the egg would likely become impermeable to sperm, similar to how Bella's amniotic sac was hardened like vampire skin.

It is questionable, then, that male vampires can continue to create sperm.  We do, however have evidence that they can - the 'father' of the non-Nessie half-vamp who is brought in at the end of the books is indicated to have been creating half-vamps for a long while, in secret.

Comment: And Edward can still pump blood to his penis? Can he have erection?

Comment: @JimThio: Yes.  In fact, the later books go into FAR too much detail about how vampires can (and DO and DO AND DO) have sexual intercourse.  It can destroy entire houses.

Comment: @Jeff - Man of Steel, Woman of Kleenex? ;)

Answer (score 7):

They are not able to, as is evidence from previous books. If they were, then it's safe to say that Carlisle and Esme Cullen would have had a baby. Also, Rosalina is quite upset that she can't have babies, leading to a large conflict in *Breaking Dawn*.

I believe it was explained that vampire females don't go through a menstrual cycle, as their bodies are immutable.

Comment: Not to mention Emmet and Rosalina would have a whole host of babies by now, instead of her being that sad.

Answer (score 1):

Vampire bodies have a very limited capacity for change.  Even if they were ovulating when changed, they wouldn't be able to make the adjustments needed to carry to term.

The real question would be about artifical  insemination and surrogates.

Answer (score 1):

Meyer specifically addressed this point in an [FAQ](http://stepheniemeyer.com/the-books/breaking-dawn/frequently-asked-questions-breaking-dawn/#pregnancy) on her official website. Apologies for the length of the quote but it's all moderately relevant.

In brief, female vampires cannot become pregnant. Male vampires are capable of sustaining an erection and impregnating human females due to the presence of "[venom](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Venom)" suffusing their cells.

> **Vampires and pregnancy: when did that idea occur to you? How does that work?**
>
> *I was always very careful when I answered the “Can vampires have
> babies?” question, because I didn’t want to say anything incorrect,
> but I also didn’t want to make the future super-obvious. **I focused my
> answers on the female half of the equation—female vampires cannot have
> children because their bodies no longer change in any aspect. There is
> no changing cycle to begin with, and their bodies couldn’t expand to
> fit a growing child, either.** I purposely evaded answering the
> question, “Can a male vampire get a human female pregnant?” to
> preserve a tiny bit of surprise in the last book. There were many
> statements on this subject purported to have come from me, but I never
> made those comments because, obviously, I knew where this was going.*
>
> *Vampires are physically similar enough to their human origins to pass
> as humans under some circumstances (like cloudy days) ... **A fluid similar
> to the venom in their mouths works as a lubricant between the cells,**
> which makes movement possible (note: this fluid is very flammable). ... **The normal reactions of arousal are still present in
> vampires,** made possible by venom-related fluids that cause tissues to
> react similarly as they do to an influx of blood. **Like with vampire
> skin—which looks similar to human skin and has the same basic
> function—fluids closely related to seminal fluids still exist in male
> vampires, which carry genetic information and are capable of bonding
> with a human ovum.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Frequently Asked Questions: Breaking Dawn - www.stepheniemeyer.com](http://stepheniemeyer.com/the-books/breaking-dawn/frequently-asked-questions-breaking-dawn/#pregnancy)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -1):

Among humans, some pathogens cross the placenta and affect the fetus while others do not.    The outcome of the vampiric conversion of a pregnant woman would probably depend on whether or not the entity responsible for the infection does so. If it does, the fetus should be sustained by the infection quite as well as the woman would be. The fetus might or might not ever be born, but there is no reason to expect a miscarriage. If pregnancy progresses, the infant should be a vampire also. If the infection does not cross the placenta, a female vampire, almost certainly non-breathing, would be unable to support a still-human fetus. It would die, and, one *hopes*, miscarry promptly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems to apply to human females who are turned after conception, but doesn't really address full vampires.  It also seems to be fairly speculative, where you should try to provide some basis from the *Twilight* Saga.

Comment: Yes it also goes for full vampires.